# unable to run docker inside a docker container (macOS)

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to run a Jenkins Docker container, which is bonded to the docker socket and docker path inside my Mac (Big Sur).
The command I run is:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d \             
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

However, if I `docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID bash` into the container and then run `docker ps` I get:

```
jenkins@67494b7442cd:/$ docker ps
bash: docker: command not found
```

On my Mac host, `which docker` outputs `/usr/local/bin/docker`
But inside the container itself, `ls /usr/bin/docker` outputs nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check that `/usr/bin/` is in the `$PATH` of the jenkins container?

Comment: Looks like it
jenkins@67494b7442cd:/$ echo $PATH
/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lisa /usr/bin | grep -i docker`?

Comment: 309    0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        40 Aug 28 19:09 docker

Comment: It seems that on my macOS host ,`/usr/local/bin/docker` is a file, while in the Docker container `/usr/bin/docker` is an empty directory.

Comment: could you try replacing `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker` with `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/`?

Comment: When I try running `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/` the container is created in the `Exited` state. `docker logs $CONTAINER_ID` outputs `/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh: line 9: find: command not found`

Comment: Then I am clueless. In any way, I would not expect that this approach will work since we only copy docker, but not its dependencies. The better way would be - as suggested by Z4-tier in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967568/4216641) to install docker in the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install docker inside the container. Try adding this to your dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache docker
```

(this assumes you are usig alpine)

Comment: I've ended up leaving the Docker socket binding `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins/jenkins` and installing Docker instead the container and it worked. `

Comment: @SimpleNiko yah, for sure you'll still need the socket mounted into the container. Glad it worked out :)